# Continuous Integration on Gitlab with a Console App

Tags: asp.net-core, gitlab, console-application, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am developing a simple console application with .NET Core 2. 
Its purpose is to clean up a Database once per day. 
This means the application does never stop after once started.

This application is part of Solution where also a .NET Core Rest API lives, to access the same database so its also part of the same Gitlab repository.

Now i want to publish and start the console app via the existing Continuous Integration pipelines of the repo. (CI pipeline is working perfectly for the REST Api project)

Building, testing and publishing works perfectly, the only problem is running the console application.

I tried a few attempts by now, the outcome is always, that the pipeline gets stuck after the application startet. I guess it is like that because it waits till the app finishes, what never happens.

I tried by now:

1. starting the app directly in the gitlab_ci.yml
   gitlab_ci.yml:

   ```
   -cd C:\publishFolder
   -DB_Cleaner.exe
   ```

   -> The application is executed directly in the Runner console
   gitlab_ci.yml:

   ```
   -cd C:\publishFolder
   -start cmd.exe /k DB_Cleaner.exe
   ```

   -> The runner is stuck till it got canceled by timeout
2. Running a bash or powershell script to run the application
   gitlab_ci.yml:

   ```
   -cd C:\ScriptFolder
   -runDBCleaner.cmd
   ```

   runDBCleaner.cmd:

   ```
   -cd C:\publishFolder
   -start cmd.exe /k DB_Cleaner.exe
   ```

-> The runner is stuck till it got canceled by timeout

Runner is running on a Win-64 virtual machine.

Is there a way to start the application to run Independent from the gitlab-CI-Runner?

Comment: were you able to achieve the desired goal ?. Can you post your own answer including all the steps for CI and CD. I have similar requirement and being new I am in stage of where to start. Please post your answer for .NET  console application gitlab CI CD .

Comment: @Gaurav Im sorry, i'v not been able to achieve it so far. 
I will post an answer if i am but from my actual point of view it does not seem to be possible

Answer (score 0):

[See This Forum](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4781). It is working for me using this script:

```
- 'powershell.exe D:\app\CiTest.exe'
```

The CiTest.exe is a .Net 4.8 console app.